# How do I approximate indoor temperature of a non-ventilated building?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, weather

How do I obtain a good approximate of the indoor temperature of a non-ventilated building (i.e., with no air conditioning) if I know the outside temperature (and possibly other factors, like humidity)?
Are there any methods to obtain such an approximation, let's say with an error of +/- 2-3 Celsius, or there aren't any reliable ones?

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Thermodynamic approach: And use 
[image: Temperature]

Q-heat flow

S-entropy

But I have to say that it easy to calculate the change in temperature, rather than calculate it.

Comment: This seems like it wouldn't help at all...

Comment: It’s easier to calculate the change in temperature, rather than calculate it... So what do you think you will do?